# Documentation on .NET Framework 4.6 support on Windows 7 Enterprise

Tags: windows-7, .net, prerequisites

The official MS system requirements states that Windows 7 SP1 does support .NET 4.6, but Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 is not explicitly mentioned.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww(v=vs.110).aspx

Is there any documentation that states that Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 is not supported?

It seems strange as Vista is supported.

Comment: Are you asking if Windows 7 without SP1 is supported? Otherwise: The whole product family including Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 is meant.

Comment: Added clarification

Comment: Adam, they didn't mention a single specific edition in that table, for any version. What makes you think that the "Enterprise" edition could be excluded?

Comment: Because I have a number of clients who are unable to deploy .NET 4.6 to Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 and the error message states the OS is not supported

Comment: So your real problem is something else entirely  ... Please edit your question to address that problem. BTW, my Windows box runs Win7EntSP1, and I have Net 4.6.1 installed.

Comment: My question is perfectly valid. It is asking if there is any documentation that states it is not supported. Your response would be "no, the system requirements does not explicitly mention the editions, so it implies Enterprise is supported, and I have a machine running Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 with 4.6.1 installed so can vouch that it is supported."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the system requirements does not explicitly mention the editions, so it implies Enterprise is supported, and I have a machine running Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 with 4.6.1 installed so can vouch that it is supported.

:)